# How to re-render component if path change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

if I'm on a movie page

```
/movie/some-movie
```

and go on link to

```
/movie/another-movie
```

component not render

react-route v4

router

```
<Route exact path="/movie/:urlRusLat" component={Movie} />
```

link

```
<Link to={'/' + item.media_type + '/' + urlRusLat(item.title || item.name) + '-' + item.id} className="result-element" key={index}>
```

I try use **componentWillReceiveProps** and send request, but i receive in props new location, like in nextProps.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log(this.props)
  if (this.props.location.pathname !== nextProps.location.pathname) {
    this.sendRequest();
  }

}

componentDidMount() {
  this.sendRequest();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.clearMovieData();
}

sendRequest = () => {
  let movieId = this.props.location.pathname.split('-');
  this.props.loadMovieData(movieId[1]);
}
```

How can i make send request if path change, or render component again?

Comment: Please provide the code. It's tough without actually code to look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use componentDidUpdate() to call the sendRequest() function. Now you get the updated props. But make sure you add a check that oldProps.location != props.location before making a sendRequest() call.